# Python library for linux to demangle MSVC decorated names

Tags: linux, c++, idapython, python

I am looking for a python library for linux which can demangle the function names which are mangled by MSVC.
for example :

> Project!??0?$allocator@D@std@@QAE@XZ

to

> Project!public: __thiscall
>   std::allocator::allocator(void)

I found that IDAPython has an API for this but I don't know how to use IDAPython in linux.

Comment: [How about this solution?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6526814/342862) [Or this.](http://ishiboo.com/~danny/Projects/vc++filt/)

Comment: I need a library of python. These are acceptable as a C++ executable solution. There is also undname.exe from MSVC which does all the work but its an EXE file so I can't use that.

Comment: From the answer @Dominik linked to, but first thing I thought as well: "Name-mangling is implementation-specific. Which compiler are you interested in?" See http://www.kegel.com/mangle.html for a good introduction.

Comment: yeah. i know. thats why i mentioned msvc in the problem description.

Comment: So what's wrong with the linked solution? Why can't a Python library (I presume you mean Python module) call external binaries? Besides, you didn't mention you were looking for a *pure Python* solution. Especially since the provided links give clues how to implement it in pure Python, if that's what you absolutely want. This site isn't for recommendations about software and I can't see what's wrong with Dominik's links for example.